# Reuse the same request inside several flows Postman/Newman

Tags: postman

I have a set of requests build in Postman. My goal is to arrange a different list scenarios using the same requests where I am able to reuse the same request in these flows, with same data or varying the inputs.

Up to know I have being duplicating, but this is tedious and error prone.

I am looking for a way of doing this that I can write these test scenarios more programmatically without duplicating requests and also be able to change data for each scenario.

Comment: This is not yet possible with Postman, see also https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-implement-dry-good-coding-practices/5500

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296875/request-reuse-in-postman). It's a bit of a hack, but the best possible way of achieving this that I'm aware of.